# I want to use a table ID to a different table that takes two of that tables ID, Entity Framework, code first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-migration, code-first

This is just something I did quickly, but it shows how I want it to be. OBS the database diagram table picture. So I want the `Team` table to have two relationships with the `Transfer` table (`OldTeamId`, `NewTeamId`), is this possible?

[image]

When I try to do the `Add-Migration` as it looks now I get a message

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Team.OldTeams' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Code:

```
public class Transfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransferDate { get; set; }
    public Player ThePlayer { get; set; }
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team OldTeam { get; set; }
    public int OldTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team NewTeam { get; set; }
    public int NewTeamId { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Tournaments = new List<Tournament>();
        Players = new List<TeamPlayer>();
        OldTeams = new List<Transfer>();
        NewTeams = new List<Transfer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] TeamLogo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }
    public Country TheCountry { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
    public List<TeamPlayer> Players { get; set; }
    public List<Transfer> OldTeams { get; set; }
    public List<Transfer> NewTeams { get; set; }
}

public class GamepediaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Map> Maps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeamPlayer> TeamPlayers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TournamentMap> TournamentMaps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }
}



[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Set.png
```

Comment: Did you create two foreign keys in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreignKey Attribute

```
public class Transfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransferDate { get; set; }
    public Player ThePlayer { get; set; }
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }   
    public Team OldTeam { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OldTeam")]
    public int OldTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team NewTeam { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NewTeam")]
    public int NewTeamId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, i tryd this but i still get the fail message when i try to do the commando Add-Migration = Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Team.OldTeams' of type 'List<Transfer>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: when you have more than one relationship between two entities you have t specify the foreign key for each navigation property So. in the class Team add the foreign key attribute on each one the two navigation properties of type  `List<Transfer>` and use the column name that will mapped to like this


       `[ForeignKey("OldTeamId")]
       public List<Transfer> OldTeams { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("OldTeamId")]
       public List<Transfer> NewTeams { get; set; }`
@byteArrayJake

Comment: ah okey, ye i got it to work, so thanks for the help Peter!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, i added this lines of code. And i changed in the script "onDelete" from Cascade to NoAction.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(m => m.OldTeams).WithOne(m => m.OldTeam).HasForeignKey(m => m.OldTeamId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(m => m.NewTeams).WithOne(m => m.NewTeam).HasForeignKey(m => m.NewTeamId);
```